# Looking for nearest unbalance downline in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

My table contains the following columns: `TransactionID, MemberID, ParentID`

This is referral program, a guy refers to 2 guys and they 2 refers another 2 guys

I want to find a nearest unbalance node from a specific member

If I try to find the nearest unbalance node of 001 then I will find MemberID "003" that not yet balance/incomplete the node.

If I try to find the nearest unbalance node of 002 then I will find memberID=004 that not yet balance/incompleted the node.

Can anyone help..

```
TransactionID   MemberID    ParentID
1               001          000
2               002          001
3               003          001
4               004          002
5               005          002
6               006          003
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You probably need a recursive CTE. Also why `004` rather than `005`?

Comment: because 004 has smaller TransactionID than 005

Comment: I don't have any idea where to start, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS pointed out by Martin Smith, a recursive CTE is needed. Here's something to get your started. It builds up a full node hierarchy and then picks up the first child node (i.e. one with the minimum depth in the hierarchy) that has fewer than 2 children. If two child nodes are tied on depth, the one with the smaller `member_id` is picked.

```
declare @starting_node varchar(100) = '001'
;with C as (
select parent_id root_parent, member_id, 1 as depth from #test where
parent_id = @starting_node
union all
select C.root_parent, #test.member_id, C.depth + 1 from #test join C on #test.parent_id = C.member_id
), C1 as (
select parent_id, count(*) number_of_immediate_children from #test 
group by parent_id
) 
select member_id from (
select C.member_id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by depth, member_id) ranker
from C left join C1 on C.member_id = C1.parent_id
where isnull(number_of_immediate_children, 0) < 2
) Z where ranker = 1
```

Comment: Oh GOD, you are my Angels, i have tested it and running well, thank you very much....

Comment: @revirinaldi, good to know! Accept the answer if it worked for you